# How to override a native constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, overriding, native

I'd like to change a RegExp constructor, to use case insensitive, but I can't modify the source.

The source calls:

```
MyExp = new RegExp("xxx","") //Native
```

Can I create a function that could override that, e.g.

```
function RegExp(a,b){
  return native.RegExp(a,"i")
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to modify native objects. You will change how this behaves not only for your code but *every single other library you are using*. If one of them used to rely on (assumed) case-sensitive matches, you take that away and even well-tested third party code can start behaving erratically.

Comment: Thanks vlaz, but this is for a specific use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). Save the old value of the native function in another variable.

```
(function(nativeRegExp) {
    window.RegExp = function(a, b) {
        return nativeRegExp(a, b || "i"); // default to case-insensitive
    }
})(RegExp);
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, this is what I am looking for. Didn't know what it is called ;-)

Comment: #1 I've used this technique a few times to intercept and log certain calls--never knew the term for it!

Comment: #2 Sadly, this only works though when the new RegExp constructor is used, not by using a RegExp literal (ie `let re = /ab+c/;`)  Wonder if there is some magic to overide that?

Comment: I doubt it. There's no requirement that the literal parser call any public functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new method:

```js
RegExp.i = function(a){
    return new RegExp(a,"i")
} 

var str = "TextToReplace";

var r = new RegExp.i("TEXTTOREPLACE");

var newStr = str.replace(r,"replaced");

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: Thanks Emeeus, but I don't have the source, so I can't can't do that.