# Override JavaScript global native Object() constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, overriding

I'm trying to override `Object()` calls in JavaScript, in order to intercept and save all the parameters passed to the object constructor.

I don't have any access to the original code since I am running from an injected code but I do run from the same scope and share the same `window` of the original code.

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339769/1380370):

```
(function (nativeObject) {
    window.Object = function (value) {
        if (value.magic) {
            window.myMagic = value.magic;
        }
        return nativeObject(value);
    }
})(Object);
```

as well as saving the original `window.Object` on `window.nativeObject` and calling it from within my hook, but in both ways I end up getting:

```
TypeError: Object.defineProperty is not a function
TypeError: Object.keys is not a function
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object.isExtensible is not a function
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object.create is not a function
```

Is it because my `window.myMagic` calls the the `Object` methods to set the `myMagic` key in the `window` object?

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: In what code do you need to intercept `Object` calls? That sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to get statistics about data being transferred in a certain web client (and don't have the access to the code). I want to set hooks on whatever built in functions I can, like `XMLHttpRequest`, `Object`, etc - and do some analytics based on it. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Transferred from where to where? But no, intercepting `Object` calls is unlikely to be effective, since most objects are constructed through other means.

Comment: @Bergi And is there any way to hook and intercept object assignments like `myObject.key = ...`?

Comment: It's possible with getters (and, if you don't know the `key` name, with proxies), but for both you must have control over `myObject` and it only works with assignments. Still not sure what your goal (or even concrete problem) is, so I can't give practical advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show how to replace the `Object` constructor with a proxy: we need to implement both the `apply` and `construct` traps for invocations of `Object` without or with `new`.

```js
(nativeObject => {
    function Object(value) {
        if (value.magic) {
            globalThis.myMagic = value.magic;
        }
        return nativeObject(value);
    }
    globalThis.Object = new Proxy(nativeObject, {
        apply: (target, thisArg, args) => Object(...args),
        construct: (target, args) => Object(...args)
    });
})(Object);

// Test
new Object({ magic: 42 });
console.log(myMagic); // prints 42
Object({ magic: 'foo' });
console.log(myMagic); // prints "foo"
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)); // prints an array of property names
```

Just note that this method will not work with any predefined functions, which may require different treatments for `apply` and `construct`. The `Object` function is a special case in that it behaves in the same way with or without `new`.

Comment: Can I use the same approach to proxy and hook [function calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)?

Comment: @amiregelz Sort of. It would take a couple of changes to make it work. Do you have a particluar example in mind?

Comment: Yes :) I want to detect when a specific function is being called by intercepting all function calls and looking at the called function signature and its string representation.

Comment: @amiregelz The difficult part is not [creating the proxy](https://jsfiddle.net/z542jeya/), but replacing the original function, and this can be done only when the the function to be intercepted is accessible at the time of proxying.

Comment: Got it. So it's not possible to proxy the `Function` built-in method/constructor to intercept all functions simultaneously?

Comment: @amiregelz nope...

Comment: It looks like it works perfectly, however I see there is some function call (in the website code which is not mine) that fails once I set this hook, and succeeds if I remove it. The error is not very clear (`every is not a function`) - but regardless - is there any chance this hook could have bad effect on some function calls?

Comment: @amiregelz It could have unexpected effects, sure.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to prevent that? aren't the parameters passed exactly the same as they would originally? what about the `this` arg?

Comment: @amiregelz `this` and the parameters are the same, but there are other differences. I would start with debugging the error you observe to find out where in your code the difference is arising.

Comment: I can't put my fingers on what's special about the code that fails, it's just a call to S3 addAuthorization (when uploading a file), which looks like a normal function call.
Is it possible to cancel the Proxy once I find my `magic`? maybe that will help avoid messing things up.

Comment: @amiregelz Certainly. Just save the original value of `Object` in a variable before installing the proxy, then when you are done with it, reset the original value with `globalThis.Object = originalObject;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing `Object` with a function that doesn't have any of the expected static methods on it. Calling `Object.defineProperties` no longer works, it's `nativeObject.defineProperties` that would be required.

You can however easily copy those properties from the native function onto your replacement function, to avoid breaking code that relies on them:

```
(function (nativeObject) {
    window.Object = function (value) {
        if (value.magic) {
            window.myMagic = value.magic;
        }
        return nativeObject(value);
    }
    for (const key of Reflect.ownKeys(nativeObject)) { // names and symbols
        const descriptor = nativeObject.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nativeObject, key);
        nativeObject.defineProperty(Object, key, descriptor);
    }
})(Object);
```

Comment: I'm getting `nativeObject.defineOwnProperty is not a function`.
Also, looking at [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) and [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy) got me thinking, is there a better or easier to create a proxy like that?

Comment: @amiregelz Ooops, now updated with tested code :-) No, a `Proxy` won't really help here.

Comment: How does this solution differ from GOTO 0's?

Comment: @amiregelz Apart from the obvious (not using an unnecessary proxy), the approach also works in an ES5 environment (ok, you'll have to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `Reflect.ownKeys` of course). Is there something specific you want to know about?