# Hooking javascript object literal constructors to modify objects created in inaccessible contexts

Tags: javascript, userscripts, object-literal

I'm attempting to modify an object present in code that I do not control and cannot directly alter. Ideally, I'd like to do this from a bookmarklet, but the extra permissions of a userscript are also a usable context.

The code I'm attempting to hook looks like this:

```js
(() => {
  var target = { nestedsubobject: { foo: 'value' } };
  // does some stuff with target
})();
```

I'd like to intercept the object literal assigned to `target` and modify the value of `foo`, before the IIFE uses it further.

So far everything I've tried that doesn't work:

- Prototypes appear unrelated to this problem. While I *can* override the global object prototype, this gives me no way to actually listen for objects created using that prototype.

  - Using `Object.defineProperty` on `Object.prototype` to define `nestedsubobject` or `foo` with `writable: false` or `get()` results in the client code throwing `TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property (...)` when constructing the target object. Configuring with `value` just results in the property being present in the new object and thus ignored in the prototype object.
- Constructors are bypassed with object literals. While I *can* override the global object *constructor* (as in [Override JavaScript global native Object() constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70489972/override-javascript-global-native-object-constructor)), the literal syntax doesn't appear to use that constructor.

Additionally, I can't alter the code directly (e.g. intercepting and rewriting the network request for it) because I expect that it may be obfuscated in the future. I'd like to directly hook object creation to make my userscript much more durable.

This is running in a browser context.

Comment: It would be a security violation if developers could proxy construction of objects like that.

Comment: Is this code running in a browser context?

Comment: @trincot this is running in a browser, I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop execution of Javascript function (client side) or tweak it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972038/stop-execution-of-javascript-function-client-side-or-tweak-it)

Comment: @double-beep unfortunately not quite. It'd work in a similar situation, but I specifically need to depend on the shape of the resulting object (which I expect to remain mostly stable) and not modify the code responsible for creating it directly (which I expect will be possibly unstable, which I wish to futureproof against potential obfuscation, and which I have further reasons for not modifying that I can't share here)